# Post multiple URL

Tags: php

I want to post multiple images by posting the url's but I don't know how to do this because I am new to PHP.

```
  <?PHP
   if(isset($_POST['post_image']))
  {
  $image_url=$_POST['image_path'];
  $data = file_get_contents($image_url);
  $new = '../images/myimage.jpg';
  $upload =file_put_contents($new, $data);
  if($upload) {
   echo "<img src='../images/myimage.jpg'>";
  }else{
   echo "Please upload only image files";
  } 
  }
  ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your script is, that you are not saving the file anywhere. So you have no access to it when trying to return it to the client.

In order to save an image using a POST you need to make sure you have set the following enctype inside your form.

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Then you can use this function to save the img

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["myImg"], "/path/to/imgDir")
```

And later show it to the client using:

```
echo "<img src='/path/to/imgDir/myImg'>"
```

For more information about the topic i advice you to consult the following URL
https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Comment: <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

Comment: so with this I can post multiple image url's ? because the client want it to be saved by url